# Java - Inversão de string palíndromo

Tags: java, string

Estou tentando fazer um exercício em que eu preciso inverter uma palavra, frase ou número e verificar se é palíndromo. Para palavras e números, já está funcionando, porém para frases ele dá erros dependendo do que for, por exemplo a frase "socorram me subi no onibus em marrocos", ele considera como não sendo palíndromo porque, ao inverter, a palavra "onibus" fica "subino", sem o espaço do "subi no", então ele considera como não sendo palíndromo, existe algum método pra resolver isso?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite um texto: ");
    /*char[] vetEntrada = entrada.toCharArray();*/

    StringBuffer StringInvertida = new StringBuffer();

    StringInvertida = inverteString(entrada);

    String SI = StringInvertida.toString();

    char[] vetSaida = SI.toCharArray();

    if (entrada.equalsIgnoreCase(SI)) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "É palíndromo: " + StringInvertida + " = " + entrada);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Vetor de verificação: ");
        int x = 1;
        for (char c : vetSaida) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "[" + x + "] " + c);
            x++;
        }

    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não é palíndromo: " + entrada + " != " + StringInvertida);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Vetor de verificação: ");
        int x = 1;
        for (char c : vetSaida) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "[" + x + "] " + c);
            x++;
        }

    }

}

private static StringBuffer inverteString(String entrada) {
    StringBuffer SB = new StringBuffer(entrada);

    SB.reverse();

    return SB;

}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue um pequeno código que fiz de acordo com a situação relatada:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String st = "socorram me subi no onibus em marrocos";
        String stAux = st.replaceAll("\\s+", "");

        String stReverse = new StringBuilder(stAux).reverse().toString();
        String stReverseAux = new StringBuilder(st).reverse().toString();

        System.out.println("Original: " + st);
        System.out.println("Invertido: " + stReverseAux);

        if (stAux.equals(stReverse))
            System.out.println("É um palíndromo");
        else
            System.out.println("Não é um palíndromo");

    }

}
```

Observe que primeiro precisamos tratar os espaços em branco da `st`, que será a nossa String principal. Feito isso, basta armazenar o valor da própria String invertida (utilizei o `StringBuilder` para simplificar o exemplo).

Por último, podemos realizar a comparação entre as duas String's. Caso sejam iguais, é um palíndromo, do contrário, não é.

Com isso você pode se basear e implementar a sua própria solução.

Bons estudos!

Comment: Certo, realmente desse modo ele confirma ser palíndromo, só que eu precisava mostrar a frase invertida, com os espaços, mas obrigado mesmo assim, tentarei achar algum método pra melhorar isso :)

Comment: Editei a resposta para essa situação.

Comment: Ok, obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Remova todos os espaços da frase original antes de inverter.

Você pode fazer isso com o seguinte comando:

```
entrada = entrada.replace(" ", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Por que não usarmos recursividade? É tão simples:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.println(palindromo("reviver", 0));
    System.out.println(palindromo("arara", 0));
    System.out.println(palindromo("rodador",0));
    System.out.println(palindromo("matheus", 0));
    System.out.println(palindromo("socoz", 0));
}

static boolean palindromo(String  a, int s)
{
    if(a.length() == s)
        return true ;
    if(a.charAt(s) == a.charAt(a.length() - ++s))
        return palindromo(a,s);
    else return false ;
}
```